# Remove words from string which are present in some set

Tags: ruby

I want to remove words from a string which are there in some set. One way is iterate over this set and remove the particular word using `str.gsub("subString", "")`. Does this kind of function already exits ?

Example string :

```
"Hotel Silver Stone Resorts"
```

Strings in set:

```
["Hotel" , "Resorts"]
```

Output should be:

```
" Silver Stone "
```

Comment: Share the whole data. Is it a sentence or what..?

Comment: have made necessary changes in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build a union of several patterns with [`Regexp::union`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#method-c-union):

```
words = ["Hotel" , "Resorts"]
re = Regexp.union(words)
#=> /Hotel|Resorts/

"Hotel Silver Stone Resorts".gsub(re, "")
#=> " Silver Stone "
```

Note that you might have to [escape](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) your words.

Comment: I know, I'll use regular expressions :)

Comment: @Stefan : So simple 1+

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract one array from another in ruby. Result is that all elements from the first array are removed from the second.

Split the string on whitespace, remove all extra words in one swift move, rejoin the sentence.

```
s = "Hotel Silver Stone Resorts"

junk_words = ['Hotel', 'Resorts']

def strip_junk(original, junk)
  (original.split - junk).join(' ')
end

strip_junk(s, junk_words) # => "Silver Stone"
```

It certainly *looks* better (to my eye). Not sure about performance characteristics (too lazy to benchmark it)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you wanted but as I understood

```
sentence = 'Hotel Silver Stone Resorts'
remove_words  = ["Hotel" , "Resorts"] # you can add words to this array which you wanted to remove
sentence.split.delete_if{|x| remove_words.include?(x)}.join(' ')
=> "Silver Stone"
```

**OR**

if you have an array of strings, it's easier:

```
sentence = 'Hotel Silver Stone Resorts'
remove_words  = ["Hotel" , "Resorts"]
(sentence.split - remove_words).join(' ')
=> "Silver Stone"
```

Comment: It is ressembles to my answer but the substraction is faster with Set I suppose. Test should be made maybe.

Comment: I just tried my way but I like Stefen's answer more clear and simple

Answer (score 0):

You could try something different , but I don't know if it will be faster or not (depends on the length of your strings and set)

```
require 'set'
str = "Hotel Silver Stone Resorts"
setStr = Set.new(str.split)
setToRemove = Set.new( ["Hotel", "Resorts"])
modifiedStr = (setStr.subtract setToRemove).to_a.join " "
```

Output

```
"Silver Stone"
```

It uses the Set class which is faster for retrieving single element (built on Hash).
But again, the underlying transformation with to_a may not improve speed if your strings / set are very big.

It also remove implicitly the duplicates in your string and your set (when your create the sets)