# Ruby:Remove only leading and trailing substring from string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to remove some substring from string but that substring should be only either be the either in the front or the end.

```
Example :- Hotel Silver Stone Residency
String to be removed :- Residency
Output :- Hotel Silver Stone 

Example :- Hotel Silver Residency Stone 
String to be removed :- Residency
Output :- Hotel Silver Residency Stone
```

Comment: Seems to be very close to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906114/remove-words-from-string-which-are-present-in-some-set.

Comment: they are not the same . .

Comment: second example will help you figure out the difference

Answer (score 2):

```
sub_str = "Residency"
s = "Residency Hotel Residency Silver Stone Residency"
s.gsub(/^#{sub_str}|#{sub_str}$/,'').strip
=> "Hotel Residency Silver Stone"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using regexp, but as I am not a regexp expert, I can show you how you can do it using split/join

```
s="Hotel Silver Stone Residency String"
string_to_be_removed="Residency"

tokens=s.split(' ')
tokens.shift if tokens.first==string_to_be_removed
tokens.pop if tokens.last==string_to_be_removed
s=tokens.join(' ')
```